# Icons at desktop visible after removed

Tags: icon, desktop, wallpaper

I had quite a few elements in my "Desktop" folder, so I cleaned it. Yet they are still visible. My "Desktop" folder is empty, yet my desktop still looks messy like this:

[image]

I see them but I cannot even click on them, they are part of the wallpaper.

PS. When I changed the wallpaper - the same, the deleted icons remained there...

How can I clean my desktop?

Comment: Do you have multiple volumes mounted? The visible desktop is the combination of all their desktop folders.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple volumes? Like USB sticks or external HDDs? No I do not use it typically. Plus, I cannot click on the icons, they are just a static background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this will work, as I cannot reproduce the issue, but you could try Relaunching the Finder.

To do this:

- Click on the Apple () menu.
- Then select the "Force Quit ..." menu item.
- This will bring up the "Force Quit Applications" popup window.
- From the list of running applications, select "Finder" after which the button will change from "Force Quit" to "Relaunch".
- Click the Relaunch button.
- Click the Relaunch button again in the confirmation dialog.

This will restart the Finder and hopefully clear away your zombie icons.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks

Comment: FYI Cmd-Option-Escape is the keyboard shortcut to bring up the Force Quit dialog. You can also use Option-Rightclick on the Finder icon in the Dock, then select Relaunch.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you set a screenshot of the Desktop as the wallpaper. If you're on Sonoma, go to System Settings > Wallpaper and change it.

Comment: The question says that they stay when they change the wallpaper, so I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Well... no. I think I would remember making a screenshot of my messy desktop and using it as a wallpaper, wouldn't I ?